# Запуск статического html из Angular2

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular5

Разместил в проекте на Angular2 в папке src файл redirect.html. Прописал название файла в angular-cli.json:

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "redirect.html"
  ],....
```

Ожидаю, что файл будет доступен по адресу http://localhost:4200/redirect.html, но выходит ошибка - Cannot GET /redirect.html. Почему Angular не видит redirect.html? Спасибо!

UPD: Вынес redirect.html из src директории, все заработало.Или нужно удалить файл webpack.congig.js

Comment: Может так попробовать в angular-cli.json:{ "glob": "redirect.html", "input": "./", "output": "./" }  ?